# Disable scripts in WebBrowser Control

Tags: .net, browser

I have a HTML page that I want to display in a WebBrowser control, I only want to preserve its layout. It can be any page downloaded, I want it to be static (non-interactive), meaning no javascript or Flash, but the user can still use scrollbars to move around the page.

I am thinking of stripping out all tags except for basic tags (img, table, etc) because I'm not familiar with different types of scripts and plugins, I only want to preserve layout. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that the `WebBrowser` control has properties to disable scripts, but if not, you can use the AntiXSS library to sanitize the HTML of all executable JavaScript.

Check it out here:

http://wpl.codeplex.com/

Comment: The WebBrowser control doesn't have any property that I could find to do that, but I will try this library, thanks.